# JButton doesn't appear until clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

For this program, the JButton doesn't seem to show up unless you click the area where the JButton should be; the JFrame starts up blank. The moment you click the button, the respective code runs and the button finally shows up.

How do I get the buttons to show up upon starting the program?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
/*
The Amazing BlackJack Advisory Tool by JoshK,HieuV, and AlvinC.
Prepare to be amazed :O
 */
public class BlckJackUI {
    //main class, will contain the JFrame of the program, as well as all the buttons.
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    //Creating the JFrame
    JFrame GUI = new JFrame("Blackjack Advisor");
    GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GUI.setSize(1300, 900);
    GUI.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Hieu Vo\\Desktop\\Green Background.png")));
    GUI.setVisible(true);
    // Because each button needs to run through the Math class.
    final Math math = new Math();
    // The Ace Button:
    ImageIcon Ace = new ImageIcon("/Users/computerscience2/Downloads/Ace.jpg");
    JButton ace = new JButton(Ace);
    ace.setSize(300, 100);
    ace.setLocation(100, 100);
    ace.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Automatically default the the Ace to 11, and if Bust, Ace becomes 1. 
            if (math.array.playerhandtotal <= 21)
            {
                math.cardvalue = math.cardvalue + 11;
            }
            else
            {
                math.cardvalue = math.cardvalue + 1;
            }
            math.array.clicktracker++;
            math.calcResult();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,math.array.result);
        }
    });
    GUI.add(ace);
    ImageIcon Two = new ImageIcon("/Users/computerscience2/Downloads/2.jpg");
    JButton two = new JButton(Two);
    two.setSize(300, 100);
    two.setLocation(100, 200);
    two.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            /*
                This generally repeats throughout the whole class, and the only
                thing different is the changing cardvalue. When a button is pressed,
                respective cardvalues are added into the playerhand ArrayList, and
                totaled up to form playerhandtotal, which is a major factor in 
                bringing up the advice.
             */
            math.cardvalue = math.cardvalue + 2;
            math.array.clicktracker++;
            math.calcResult();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,math.array.result);
        }
    });
    GUI.add(two);
```

Et cetera, Et cetera... Just a bunch of the same stuff, more buttons coded the same exact way as JButton two, but with different value associated to them.

```
    JButton start = new JButton("Start/Reset");
    start.setSize(300, 100);
    start.setLocation(500,500);
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            /*
            The start button also acts like a reset button, and the concept is fairly
            simple. If we reset all the important values to 0 or "null," then the 
            program acts as if it was just opened.
             */
            Arrays array = new Arrays();
            array.playerhand.clear();
            array.dealer = 0;
            math.array.starttracker++;
            math.array.clicktracker = 0;
            array.playerhandtotal = 0;
            math.cardvalue = 0;
            array.result = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select the card \nthat the dealer is showing :)");

        }
    });
    GUI.add(start);
    GUI.setLayout(null);
```

This is all in the same class, and I understand a layout would be nicer, but perhaps there's a way to fix this issue using what I have now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program starts blank because you are calling `setVisible` before you add components. Call `setVisible` after you add components (in the end of contructor) and it should work fine.
Also, avoid absolute positioning and call of set|Preferred|Minimum|MaximumSize methods for your components. Learn how to use layout managers.

Comment: You should say at the end of the constructor, not the end of the code, You might confuse the OP. +1 btw

Comment: @peeskillet Corrected. But just as a notice, he doesn't necessary have to call `setVisible` in the end of constructor. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, haha. Should've figured that out myself. I understand that I should learn how to use layout managers, but haven't got there yet. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Write GUI.validate(); after you add all the components to your frame. Any time you add something to a frame you have to validate it like this. Otherwise, you will get the behavior that you have described.

Answer (score 0):

No. The problem is caused by the layout. Before adding anything to a JFrame or a JPanel which you want it to have an absolute position, you have to setLayout(null). Otherwise, you'll have unexpected behaviours all the time. I just figured it out by myself after three hours of experimenting; suddenly, I connected your post with other different subject, and it worked, but this isn't well explained on the Internet yet.